# How to convert a literal string of hex to actual hex values in C++?

Tags: c++, hex

I have a string of hex values stored in a single string, such as:

```
string ex = "9715AF";
```

Where I want to store it in an array, as actual hex values:

```
unsigned char byteList[] = { 0x97, 0x15, 0xAF };
```

Is this something that's possible? I was trying to convert them to ASCII then decimal, but this didn't work out so well. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Get two characters at a time, convert each to its integer equivalent, put them together into a single byte, add the byte to your "list".

Comment: C++ integers only have values, not hex values and decimal values So `{ 0x97, 0x15, 0xAF }` is exactly the same as `{ 151, 21, 175 }`

Comment: If you want help with your current attempt, then please create a [mre] of it and show it to us, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: "but this didn't work out so well. " What is *this*?